# Laravel can not link storage on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, storage, production

I have just recently uploaded my Laravel site to shared hosting, but I am not getting my link to storage to work. Uploading images through my controllers does not work, but I'm assuming it's because the link is not correctly set up in the production environment

Doing php artisan storage:link gives me the error **symlink(): No such file or directory**. From checking some other posts, it seemed like the solution was to simply delete the old storage folder in the public file, but this action did not solve my issue.

I have also read in some way that you could manually create a link, but how would that be done?

My method for storing the image is as follows:

```
if (request('img_path')) {
            $imagePath = request('img_path')->store('project_images', 'public');
        }
```

Is this a correct way, or is there some other way to do this? With Storage::, or similar?

Any one have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you changed the permissions on the storage and bootstrap folders (and their subfolders) to make them writable? These folders need to be made writable on the server

Comment: @user6854465 What exactly is it that need to be changed in these permissions?

Comment: As the storage folder should be outside your public folder, you could try experimenting with changing the permissions on it to 665 for a minute to see if that fixed your problem...are you using FTP to upload your site? If so, try right-clicking the storage and bootstrap folders in your FTP client and selecting 'Change permissions' (or whatever option mentions file/folder permissions) and ticking 'read' and 'write' for owner and group, and ticking just the 'read' option for everyone else (so you might see the numbers 665 somewhere, depending on your ftp client)

Comment: @user6854465 Yes I am using Filezilla to upload the files to the server. Changing the permission didn't seem to do anything, though it set the numbers to 775, and when I tried to manually change the numbers, it would just shut down the Filezilla client without any error message or anything